# Downloaded image not visible on selected android modals?

Tags: android

I have android code which creates an image and saves them. For most of the user everything works fine, but for a few, they are unable to view the picture, what could be the possible reason?

Here is my code snippet for creating image

```
public static String takeScreenshot(View view, boolean temp) {
        String name;
        if (temp) {
            name = "last_shared";
        } else {
            Date now = new Date();
            name = (String) android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss", now);
        }

        // create directory if it does not exist
        File folder = new File(Environment
                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) +
                "/Quoted");
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            // NOTE: Should this be mkdirs()?
            folder.mkdir();
        }

        try {
            // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
            // String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Quoted/quote_" + name + ".jpg";
            String mPath = Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                    .toString() + "/Quoted/quote_" + name + ".jpg";
            view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
            view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

            File imageFile = new File(mPath);

            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            int quality = 100;
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            return mPath;

            //openScreenshot(imageFile);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // Several error may come out with file handling or OOM
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }


    public static void refreshGallery(String filename, Context context) {
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context,
                new String[]{filename}, null,
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        Log.d("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                        Log.d("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                    }
                }
        );
    }
```

The issue is happening on device like Xiaomi Redmi 3S Android 6.0 and Asus ZenFone 2 Android 6.0.

I have tested app on other 6.0 devices and it works just well.

As far as I can think, the cause could be:
1. `Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES` is not resolving for these phones. So should I use `mkdirs()` instead?
2. Whatever I am doing is it the right way to do it?

If anyone has faced similar issues please help me. I would love any kind of hints. Thanks.

Comment: `unable to view the picture? - what does it mean? Picture doesn't no appear in gallery? Or file on file system doesn't exist? Do you have stack trace of exception?

Comment: There are no exceptions. All I was told is that images are not visible in the gallery after download. I have asked some users to check via the file explorer if the file exist. I am still waiting on the response.

Comment: I think the only way for you is to create small project which reproduce problem on that devices, and ask someone with that device to collect logs.

Comment: I was planning on borrowing the similar device from a friend and do the debugging myself.

Comment: ye, it's good idea